# Regexreplace text with a variable text

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, replace, textjoin

I want to replace "username" before file extentions with the custom names in column D regardless of variations in the rest of the text. The username is variable.
I tried `substitute` function but it's replaces all the occurrences of username.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(.+ - )")&D2:D&
                   REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(\s?\.[a-z]+$)")))
```

[image]

```
.        single character
.+       multiple characters
(.+ - )  group of all characters followed by space, dash and space
\s       space
\s?      space if exists
\.       dot
[a-z]    any lowercase character
[a-z]+   group of lowercased characters
$        end of the string
```

Comment: The tailing space is removed  `... john doe[Space].png | ...APBhz[?].png`  can it be done without clipping it If present keep it. can you add it as option 2 in the answer?

Comment: Can explain `"(.+ - )"` and `"(\.[a-z]+$)"`

Comment: @NullCat answer updated

Comment: Player0 I do not control the charachter case there is lower, upper case and capitalized.

Comment: @NullCat file extensions are usualy lowercased by design. but if you worry you can use `(?i)[a-z]+` instead of `[a-z]+`.

Comment: I see, we're capturing the extension rather than the username, Thank.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, the issue with the regexmatch from the `find` UI function of Google Sheets is that the whole document/tab will be searched to find matches.

Since the value to be replaced is not always the same, in fact, each row has its corresponding new value, so I believe the best approach to solve this is to use Apps Scripts.

The idea of the script would be to loop through rows, store the new username column of that row, search for the pattern to be replaced on the `Data` column and replace it with the stored new username.

You may use Javascript's String method [replace()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) which also accepts regex as a search pattern parameter.

And [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets#reading_data) you may find an example of how to read/write data of a Sheets file using Apps Script.